# Is it possible to use @ContentChild with a base class?

Tags: angular

So, I have a base component which contains functionality, and on top of that, I have created three (with plans to create many more) subclasses of component. The subclasses all share the same base component functionality, but they add their own to it.

I also have a wrapper component whose purpose is to provide consistent rendering for the subclass components. It does this by using `<ng-content>` tags.  All of this is working fine.

On this wrapper component, if I set a `@ContentChild(SubclassOne)` to find that type of subclass, it has no problem figuring out that the item assigned to `ng-content` is of the `SubclassOne` type, and I can interact with properties on both the subclass and the base class. The problem is that I would have to do this once for each type of subclass, and that would break the principle of abstraction.  But, when I try to use `@ContentChild(BaseComponent)`, it fails.

Is this an angular limitation, or am I doing something wrong?